# How can I get a list of all variables in a binding?

Tags: ruby, binding

Does a `Binding` know the variables it stores? Or do I always have to use this in conjunction with `local_variables`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the list of local variables in a binding by doing `eval("local_variables", the_binding)`.

I'm not sure whether that's what you meant by "Or do I always have to use this in conjunction with `local_variables`?", but there's no way to get the list without invoking `local_variables` somehow.

Comment: I was thinking the binding had a method which would list all the values it contained ( so that I wouldn't have to pass along the array returned by `local_variables` )

Comment: Well, you don't have to pass it along because you can get it at any time using eval. There is no method though, unless you define one `class Binding; def variables() self.eval("local_variables") end end`

Comment: There is now a method `local_variables` for `Binding`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, so the answer is correct for Ruby version <= 2

But since 2.1 new methods have appeared to get/set and list local variables:

```
local_variable_get  / local_variable_set / local_variable_defined?
```

Comment: How do any of these methods list local variables?

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [`local_variables`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variables) method now which does exactly what @sepp2k's answer suggests.

From the documentation:

```
 local_variables → Array
```

Returns the names of the binding’s local variables as symbols.

```rb
def foo
  a = 1
  2.times do |n|
    binding.local_variables #=> [:a, :n]
  end
end
```

This method is the short version of the following code:

```rb
binding.eval("local_variables")
```